Solving for a moving point intersecting a moving line
Suppose that you have a moving point in space defined by $\vec{P}(t) = (X(t), Y(t))$ and you have a line centred on the origin which rotates about the origin over time so that $Y(x, t) = A(t) x$ and $A(t) = \tan(\theta(t))$. Is it possible to find the values of $t$ where the point exists on the line? If not generally, then is it possible for the case where the point is moving along a straight line and the rotating line rotates at a constant rate? (eg: $\vec{P}(t) = (at + b, ct + d)$ and $\theta(t) = jt$)?
I tried working this out myself by substituting into the equation but I quickly reach a point where I am stumped for how to find an exact solution when trying to solve for $t$:
$$
\begin{align*}
    P_x(t) &= at + b\\
    P_y(t) &= ct + d\\
    Y(x) &= A(t)x\\
    \\
    ct + d &= A(t)(at + b)\\
    ct + d &= A(t)at + A(t)b\\
    0 &= A(t)at + A(t)b - ct - d\\
    0 &= (A(t)a - c)t + A(t)b - d\\
    \\
    A(t) &= \tan(\theta(t))\\
    \theta(t) &= jt\\
    A(t) &= \tan(jt)\\
    \\
    0 &= (a\tan(jt) - c)t + b\tan(jt) - d\\
    \\
\end{align*}
$$
I realize that it should be possible to numerically approximate a solution, but I was hoping that there might exist an exact solution. Since $\tan$ is a periodic function there will be a family of solutions but my skills fail at this point in trying to determine the exact form of that.
My gut feeling is that there should always exist a solution for the above since over the interval $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ every point in 2d space will lie on the line $Y(x) = \tan(\theta)x$.

$$\frac{Y(t)}{X(t)} = \theta(t)$$

Since it is a transcendental equation, numerical approach is the only way to go...

It is not hard to see in the general case that there is no reason such a point of intersection should exist. Particularly since in your math model, the line is constrained to never be vertical. (A vertical line does not have an equation of the form $Y = Ax$.) However, that is a limitation of your model, not of the problem itself. If you consider $t$ to be the $z$-coordinate, your specific problem is a line in 3D space, not lying in a plane perpendicular to the $t$ axis, while the "moving line" is now a spiral surface which will intersect the line of the "moving point" infinitely many times.

Students at your level are very commonly obsessed with finding "exact solutions", thinking these are somehow better than "numerical approximations". But they don't realize that all their "exact solutions" do is hide the numerical approximation under another level of symbolism. You say $\sqrt 2$ is exact, but to this day, over 3 thousands years after it was first discovered, we still do not know the exact value of $\sqrt 2$, nor will we ever know, because to know it requires an infinite amount of knowledge. All we have is a numerical approximation of it.
